# Where does Captain America's shield come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame* Steve Rogers

> comes back to the present

and brings the shield with him.

How did Steve manage to bring it or even possess it?

I am going in with the assumption that there is only 1 shield. It was buried in ice along with him during the events of *Captain America: The First Avenger*. He wields it till *Captain America: Civil War* and leaves it after fighting with Tony.  In *Avengers:Endgame*,  Tony gives it back to Steve. It is broken in the fight so Steve wields Mjolnir and takes it back with him at the end when he has to return the stones.

So, where did this extra shield come from?

Comment: Wasn't Tony Stark making one in the first Iron Man movie? I suppose Steve could have somehow acquired that one.

Comment: Swapped it with the original Cap on the sly? *Original Cap prepping for a mission later: "Hey now, what happened to my shield?"* :P

Answer (score 7):

As per [one of the directors](https://screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-captain-america-peggy-carter-ending-explained/):

> If Cap were to go back into the past and live there, he would create a branched reality. The question then becomes, how is he back in this reality to give the shield away? Interesting question, right? Maybe there’s a story there. There’s a lot of layers built into this movie and we spent three years thinking through it, so it’s fun to talk about it and hopefully fill in holes for people so they understand what we’re thinking.

This essentially confirms that Cap branched reality when he went to be with Peggy, and that he's returned to the "main" timeline (somehow) to pass on the shield to Sam.

It's therefore logical that he's brought the shield from that timeline which, since it was branched off from the original reality, likely never had the exact same sequence of events resulting in its destruction.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's not the same shield. There are at least two, and possibly three Captain America shields in the unaltered MCU timeline. Whether the other one (or two) have the same properties as the original are an open question.

In Spider-Man: Homecoming (2018), one of the items that Happy Hogan mentions is being loaded up on the transport carrier is [a new shield for Captain America](https://www.cbr.com/spider-man-homecoming-captain-america-shield/).  This may or may not have been the same shield [Tony Stark was building](https://www.firstshowing.net/2008/captain-americas-shield-found-in-iron-man/) in Iron Man (2008)

This transport carrier subsequently crashes on Coney Island as a result of the fight between Spider-Man and the Vulture. If Captain America knew where and when the plane crash occurred, he could have slipped in amongst the first responders, and recovered it from the wreckage.

If there can be only one, though, then an alternate option: The shield that Tony Stark has in Iron Man is not being built, it's being repaired. How Steve got the remains into Past  Tony Stark's hands without revealing too much would be an interesting question.